# radial menu using raphaeljs

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, wheelnav.js

[image]

First i have tried wheelnav.js but it doesn't have label support. So i have tried using Raphel.js and completed sectors and placed icon .
But i am facing problem while placing text and rotating according to sector angle.

```
var rap = new Raphael($('#radialMenu')[0], 320, 320);

    var startAngle = 0,endAngle = 72,middleAngle = (startAngle+endAngle)/2;

    sector = rap.sector(150,150,150,startAngle,endAngle,{fill: "#fff" , stroke: '#ccc', "stroke-width": 2});

    icon = sector.paper.image('images/people1.png',150+95*Math.cos(-startAngle*rad),150+95*Math.sin(-startAngle*rad) ,7,40)
    .transform('r-'+middleAngle+','+150+','+150);
```

Any one please suggest me on svg or raphael.js

JSfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/maheshchari/23ngqkfe/1/
here i am getting problem aligning icon and text as per required.

Comment: I would post a jsfiddle and explain the problem a bit further.

Comment: Thanks Ian, please let me know if any clarification required on my issue, actually i posted code for only single sector ,but from array of menu it should dynamically built.

Comment: As mentioned, posting up a fiddle explaining what part doesn't work will be helpful for anyone.

Comment: Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/maheshchari/23ngqkfe/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should add another rotation angle without coordinate of the centre of rotation. If cx & cy aren’t specified centre of the shape is used as a point of rotation.

```
.transform('r-' + middleAngle + ',' + 150 + ',' + 150 + 'r90');
```